# IAM based authentication for GCP HTTPS Load Balancers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, gcp-load-balancer

I have an internal HTTPS load balancer in GCP and I need to attach IAM policy to it to restrict the ingress requests from other compute instances. I'm rather confused by GCP IAM and wonder if it's possible to set up IAM policy for my load balancer to only allow the traffic from certain compute instances/service accounts.

For example, I have 2 instances running with service account A (A@developer.gserviceaccount.com) and B (B@developer.gserviceaccount.com) respectively, I need to set the IAM policy for my load balancer to only accept requests from VM that runs with service account A.

So I have run gcloud cli on my load balancer's backend using the following policy:

```
gcloud compute backend-services set-iam-policy https-backend policy.json
```

Content of policy.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "role": "roles/compute.loadBalancerAdmin",
      "members": ["serviceAccount:A@developer.gserviceaccount.com"]
    }
  ]
}
```

I thought this policy would effectively only allow service account A to access the load balancer as compute.loadBalanceAdmin but apparently I can still hit the load balancer from VM that runs with service account B.

Comment: You can manage Google Cloud resources using IAM policies and conditions This means creating, updating, deleting, etc the resource (the load balancer). In your question, compute engine instances are not accessing the resource to manage it (create, delete, etc). It is using the service provided by the resource (compare managing compute engine with accessing the web server running within compute engine). That access is managed via VPC firewall rules or IAP for supported backeds (Identity Aware Proxy).

Comment: Your policy grants the role `roles/compute.loadBalancerAdmin` to the identity `serviceAccount:A@developer.gserviceaccount.com` for API requests to the Google Cloud  Resource Manager endpoint and not for TCP/HTTP requests sent to the load balancer's IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, but it's not exactly that.

When you create an internal Load Balancer, you have an IP address (you can set it ephemeral, but it's better to have a static one.)

Therefore, if you want to grant, or to deny traffic between your VMs and the load balancer, you have to use firewall rules.

One of the cool feature of firewall rules is that you can use a service account as the source of the traffic. Like that, you can grant the A and B service account to access the load balancer through firewall filtering.

[image]

Comment: thanks - I'll give it a go. But out of curiosity, does that mean GCP doesn't support IAM based access control on load balancers?

Comment: IAM control Google Services. You can grant IAM role to let the adminitration of the load balancer. But for the traffic, IAM does not interfere, it's network services that handle the traffic (firewall, router,...). You can use traffic identity (use the service account identity to grant or deny network traffic on Firewall rules.). One exception: you can activate IAP on external HTTPS load balancer to check requester identity against IAM permissions.

Comment: thank you! that makes sense. For my use case, it's an internal HTTPS load balancer and I've engaged GCP support who told me that BCE license is required to enable IAP on ILBs.